# ImageButton in Linear Layout not clicked. Setting Listener from service

Tags: android, android-service, android-imagebutton

This is different from the other post of this nature because I am in a service so I cannot name the `onClickListener` through XML I have to do it programatically.

I have a `ImageButton` in this XML file (it is at the very bottom):

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<HorizontalScrollView> ... </HorizontalScrollView>

<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="3dp"
    android:background="@color/light_grey" />


<FrameLayout> ... </FrameLayout>

<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="3dp"
    android:background="@color/light_grey" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="3">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/deletebutton"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:contentDescription="Delete Button"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:background="@drawable/simplerect"
        android:src="@drawable/deletebtn24dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

I then set the `onClickListener` in my service like this:

```
ImageButton deleteBtn = (ImageButton) mainKeyboard.findViewById(R.id.deletebutton);
    deleteBtn.setOnClickListener(new android.view.View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view1) {
            Log.i("DEBUG_TAG","Button being clicked");
            getCurrentInputConnection().setComposingText("",1);
            getCurrentInputConnection().deleteSurroundingText(10000,10000);
        }

    });
```

However the `onClickListener` is not being called. I'm not sure what to do, since this is the only way I can set the listener because I am doing this from a service and not a `Activity`

Comment: why you want to set the clickListener from within a service?

Comment: @Opiatefuchs I am making a keyboard app. So the service controls to the keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that I needed to add the following attribute to the `Linear Layout` that contained the button:

```
 android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```